# How to set value in input type text with value in textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript

For this code it's work good:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<textarea style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
<p id="preview"></p>        
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    $('#preview').html($('textarea').val());
}, 10);
</script>
```

But when I change from `<p>` to `<input` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<textarea style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="preview">
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    $('#preview').html($('textarea').val());
}, 10);
</script>
```

Why it's not working? How can I resolve it?

Comment: share your code here

Comment: because you need to change the value of your input and not the html inside it

Answer (score 1):

Use .val instead .html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<textarea style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
  <input type="text" id="preview">
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval(function() {
   $('#preview').val($('textarea').val());
    }, 10);
</script>
```